# Would you award a bounty without marking any answer as correct?

Tags: discussion, bounties

The case is that I have a question where I feel none of the answers are correct, but I think it's unfair to leave a bounty unawarded.

So, I will award the bounty to the most voted question, leaving the community to decide once I really think none of those answers are correct.

Is this the expected way of solving this situation?

Comment: If you don't award it, half of it will go to the most upvoted answer. Would that be ok?

Comment: Well, I **will** award the whole bounty because I think leaving it unawarded is unfair with those who answer, but I don't know if the community expects another way of solving this situation.

Answer (score 6):

It's really all up to you. There is no "expected way" to reward a bounty as it's your reputation points and 100% your decision.

That said, "incorrect" as in doesn't help you with your specific case, does not always mean "wrong" or "not useful to others". If you feel there is answer that is helpful to others and useful, granting it the bounty would be smart move indeed to reward its author. It doesn't have to be the most upvoted answer, if there are several answers of equal quality maybe it's even better to reward the one less upvoted to compensate the author.