# Is it ok to choose a different answer for a bounty award than the one I accept?

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

I placed a bounty on one of my questions, and I'm thinking of accepting one answer but awarding a bounty to another. Is this possible and is it socially acceptable? (Re the former, [it looks like it's possible](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/), but re the latter it seems a bit of a strange thing to do.)

Roughly speaking, my reasoning is that one of the answers that came in *after* I placed the bounty shows a lot of effort and tackled some specific issues that I raised, using skills I didn't have. But another, earlier answer might be a nicer summary answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184078/152859 (my answer there quite fit here as well)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this possible and is it socially acceptable?

Yes, it is both possible and acceptable.

It is entirely up to you what answer to accept and what answer to award a bounty for - this is not something for anyone else to tell you.

Answer (score 6):

Simple Answer Yes you can.
Bounty is the extra points which you want to offer.

If you feel that the other answer than what you have accepted is a good one which must be appreciated for efforts with a bounty then you can.

Read more at **https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty**

Answer (score 3):

Definitely. I'd say that the bounty goes to the *best* answer, while the one you accept is the one that you used to fix your problem. The two aren't always the same. For example, someone might post a brilliant solution to the problem you described, but you may be unable to use it because it uses a third-party thing your boss won't let you install, or because you're working on weird hardware that can't handle it, or because it conflicts with something strange you're doing elsewhere in the code. You might not have mentioned these problems in your question (perhaps you didn't realise at the time that they might become problems), in which case the genius solution is perfectly valid, and therefore worthy of the bounty, but you personally can't use it in that particular situation, so it can't be accepted as the answer.